Turning off/Disconnecting a section of circuitry using a logic level NMOS
I am currently designing a PCB that contains some circuitry that draws current passively which I would like to disconnect from power (stop it from drawing current) once it has served its purpose. Here are the circuit's (it's an IR transceiver circuit with it's output connected to a comparator) . My PCB is a 4 layer board with a ground and 3.3V power plane. My plan was to connect all of the positive voltage rails to the 3.3v power plane and then connect all of the grounds together and connect them to ground through a logic level NMOS (SI2302) which I would power with a GPIO pin. The circuit would look something like this . I am skeptical about joining all the grounds together. Would this approach work also is the a simpler solution. Thanks for your help!!

I really hope the values shown for R4/R5 and R15/R17 on your schematic are incorrect!

these optocouplers make no sense, if you're connecting your R14 and R32 (I guess these are your loads?) to the same 3.3V voltage rail, anyways.

Is only one of R4/R5 and one of R15/R17 supposed to be populated, it order to select a pull-up to either the 3.3 V or 5.2 V rail? The way the schematic is shown with both resistors appearing to be populated, the 3.3 V and 5.2 V rails will be shorted together.

Except the load is some simple circuitry like Leds (not a precision parts) I would preffer to disconnect a Vcc with P-mos.

Yes R4/R5 and R15/R17 are there because I am unsure what voltage I need to drive the IR receiver side of the circuit with (I am just going to solder bridge the correct branch)

For arguments sake lets say I can drive the circuit with 3.3v, aka ignore both 5v sources as well as the 0 ohm resistors. So all of the 3.3v sources will be connected to my PCB's power plane, now how could I disconnect them/ stop them for drawing current once they have served their purpose?

If you connect the P-mos this way it doesn’t matter what the Vcc is:


So could I treat the label which connects off to the disconnected circuit as a 3.3v (or 5v) power source which I can turn off and on or would there be a significant voltage drop over the PMOS? Also what MOSFETs would you recommend, the disconnect signal will be a 3.3v logic signal from an microcontroller and the PCB is really small so the mosfets would need to ne quite small (I was looking into using the SI2302 NMOS as it is quite small)
